# Strategies to offset the effects of row-wise correction from missing data

Tags: r, row, normalization

Here's a dataset

```
data <- t(data.frame(met1 = c(2,2,2,2,2),
                   met2 = c(5,4,NA,2,1),
                   met3 = c(2,2,2,NA,2),
                   met4 = c(2,4,6,8,6),
                   met5 = c(1,3,4,7,2)))
```

This gives:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
met1    2    2    2    2    2
met2    5    4   NA    2    1
met3    2    2    2   NA    2
met4    2    4    6    8    6
met5    1    3    4    7    2
```

I often conduct row-wise correction on my dataset. Which divide all the values after summing, meaning that all the values are between 0 and 1.

```
data <- data / rowSums(data, na.rm = TRUE)
```

This works great when there's no missing data.
But as you can see when comparing `met1` and `met3`, each value of `met3` is considerably higher than `met1` due to the missing data.

```
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
met1 0.20000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.20000000
met2 0.41666667 0.3333333        NA 0.1666667 0.08333333
met3 0.25000000 0.2500000 0.2500000        NA 0.25000000
met4 0.07692308 0.1538462 0.2307692 0.3076923 0.23076923
met5 0.05882353 0.1764706 0.2352941 0.4117647 0.11764706
```

How could I offset this effect?
Currently I've removed any column with missing data, but I prefer not doing so as some important data could be removed.

Comment: You could divide by mean of each row `data / rowMeans(data, na.rm = TRUE)` but then the value is not between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

You may take the mean by counting `NA` in denominator, but that would make values in `met3`  "significantly" less than `met1`. One more option is to impute the missing values by row mean and then normalize them by using `rowSums()`.

```
# Data
data <- t(data.frame(met1 = c(2,2,2,2,2),
                     met2 = c(5,4,NA,2,1),
                     met3 = c(2,2,2,NA,2),
                     met4 = c(2,4,6,8,6),
                     met5 = c(1,3,4,7,2)))
> data
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
met1    2    2    2    2    2
met2    5    4   NA    2    1
met3    2    2    2   NA    2
met4    2    4    6    8    6
met5    1    3    4    7    2

# Data imputation
data = apply(data, 1, function(x) {
  x[is.na(x)] = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  return(x)
}) %>% t()
> data
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
met1    2    2    2    2    2
met2    5    4    3    2    1
met3    2    2    2    2    2
met4    2    4    6    8    6
met5    1    3    4    7    2

# Normalizing
data <- data / rowSums(data, na.rm = TRUE)
> data
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
met1 0.20000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.20000000
met2 0.33333333 0.2666667 0.2000000 0.1333333 0.06666667
met3 0.20000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.20000000
met4 0.07692308 0.1538462 0.2307692 0.3076923 0.23076923
met5 0.05882353 0.1764706 0.2352941 0.4117647 0.11764706
```

Comment: oh thanks, I wasn't actually expecting a reply since it seems to be quite a difficult problem. but, in this case, didn't you introduce and kept false values? I'm not sure whether this is a good idea.

Comment: Not exactly, when you can't remove missing values but they screw up your analysis, imputation is a good choice. Read more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)

Comment: Oh thanks for this.
I ended up trying out an alternative method where I replace NA with very low values. Due tothe nature of my data, it was likely that the NA was due to technology inability to detect low values.

Comment: That is correct. If you're sure that low values cause NA, then its better to impute with low value rather than mean.